# Fedora 17 vim core dumps with Segmentation fault (/usr/bin/vi is ok)

Tags: vim, fedora, fedora-17

New install of Fedora 17 from DVD. Trying to put my vim config together (.vim stuff) and noticed when I run `/usr/bin/vim` it dumps?

Some bugs were filed but I cant seem to find a newer version of vim 7.3 including patches 1-415, 417-682.

Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Info:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Oct 15 2012 09:56:46)
Included patches: 1-415, 417-682
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs
-dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv
+insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape
+mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse
+mouse_xterm +mouse_urxvt +mouse_sgr +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme
+netbeans_intg +path_extra +perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile
 +python/dyn -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind
+signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax
+tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse
+textobjects +title -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual
+visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup
-X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim73"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I/usr/local/include  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall  -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4  -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-z,relro -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/CORE  -Wl,-z,relro  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim       -lm -lnsl  -lselinux  -lncurses -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl    -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/CORE  -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc

/usr/bin/vim
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling vim, the program might be mangled ("rpm -Vf /usr/bin/vim" will tell you; "yum reinstall /usr/bin/vim" will reinstall the package).

Try updating ("yum update" should do it).

Make sure nothing in your setup (~/.exrc or such) gives it fits (if something does, I'm sure a bug report will be wellcome).

(Very weird. An often used program that spontaneously crashes won't pass the most eleemntary QA).

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same behaviour on a fresh install of Fedora 18.  I fixed it by removing both vim-command-t and vim-nerdtree.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue, vi would crash with a segfault every time. I found that vim-command-t was missing on my system. Installing this package fixed the issue. I am using Fedora 17